# subversion intermittently hangs (stalls) on commit

Tags: active-directory, svn, tortoisesvn, subversion-edge, collabnet

Whenever any of our SVN users try to commit to the repository after the server has been idle for a while (e.g., first commit of the day), the Commit dialog hangs for precisely one minute, regardless of the size of the commit. When the commit finishes, the status message displays something like “5 kBytes transferred in 1 minute(s) and 0 second(s)”. Subsequent commits proceed without any delay. I read on another forum a suggestion that it might have to do with LDAP caching, but I don’t know how one might investigate that. 
Can you explain what might be causing this?

UPDATE: 
I am using SVN on a locally owned server, installed by SubversionEdge from CollabNet (v5.2.2), along with TortoiseSVN 1.10. The backend is ActiveDirectory (maintained on a separate corporate server). The LDAP is configured through SubversionEdge. I have access to the settings page, but they are all greek to me (I don't have any LDAP expertise).

UDPATE #2: I suspect this problem may be related to the one described by Gerald, [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/825528/debugging-a-timeout-with-ldap-auth-on-apache). However, that one was resolved by adjusting `LDAPConnectionPoolTTL`, but that setting is not available on the Authentications page for my SVN/LDAP settings, so I do not know how to adjust it.

Comment: More information about the server setup would be helpful. What kind of SVN server? How is the authentication configured? What is the backend, ActiveDirectory, a different LDAP?

Comment: A shot in the dark, but the 1 minute delay reminds me of [this problem I had](https://serverfault.com/questions/825528/debugging-a-timeout-with-ldap-auth-on-apache).

Comment: @GeraldSchneider: I have updated my question, but not sure I've given you the details you need. Your other post is very interesting; I have posted a follow up question there

Comment: your comment there is not very useful, as it's not related to that question. You should discuss your problem only here. I'm afraid I'm not familiar with SubversionEdge, maybe someone else can shed some light on this. But I suspect a similar problem as I had. I added the relevant tags so It can be found more easily.

Comment: Thank you for your help, @GeraldSchneider. I have removed the question from the other page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [GeraldSchneider's detailed description of a similar issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/825528/debugging-a-timeout-with-ldap-auth-on-apache) I was able to identify that the problem had to do with an LDAP authentication setting known as `LDAPConnectionPoolTTL`. The challenge was to find out how to adjust that setting within the CollabNet administration portal. It is *not* on the Authentication page. Rather, you must navigate to "Server Settings", then click the "Advanced Settings" link, and at the bottom of *that* page there are these two fields:

`Connection Pool TTL` (default: -1 -- attempt to reuse connections indefinitely)

and,

`Timeout` (default: 60 seconds; this corresponds to the LDAP response time)

I am not exactly sure what the optimal settings for those fields are. I have found numerous suggestions on various forums:

- [Gerald's post](https://serverfault.com/questions/825528/debugging-a-timeout-with-ldap-auth-on-apache) suggested setting the Pool TTL to 0, disabling the reuse of existing connections, but it is unclear to me what performance hit this might incur.
- [One forum](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57203) suggested 60 seconds on Pool TTL
- [Two](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4061&dsMessageId=3166441) [other](https://subversion.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=3&dsMessageId=587462) forums suggested 900 on the Pool and 10 for the Timeout (along with some [additional changes to the httpd.conf file](https://subversion.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=3&dsMessageId=587604)).
- [Atlassian recommends](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/configuring-the-ldap-connection-pool-229838451.html) 30 seconds on the Pool TTL, and [IBM recommends](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSRMWJ_7.0.1/com.ibm.isim.doc/reference/ref/ref_ic_enroleprops_ldappool.htm) 10.

Personally, I have decided to experiment with a setting of 899 for the Pool TTL and reducing the LDAP response timeout to 10.